# Connect to an Entity Model using Reflection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection

I'm writing a little utility to load Entity Data Models from an assembly and query against them.

I've tried using Reflection to load a derived `ObjectContext`, but `ObjectContext` doesn't derive from `MarshalByRefObject` so I can't pass parameters to the constructor with `Activator.CreateInstance()` (according to the exception I get.)

**Is it possible to load an Entity Model defined and stored in an external assembly using Reflection, "late bind" to the EDM, and perform queries against it if you provide a valid connection string?**

Comment: Can't you add a helper class to the assemblies?

Comment: I'd prefer to be able to hook into the EDM in any assembly without any special preparation of the assembly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe ObjectContext.Metadataworkspace.LoadFromAssembly() is what your looking for:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb495513.aspx

Comment: This is exactly it!  With a few other reflection tricks I'm able to connect to an assembly with an EDM, point to a database, and query without knowing anything about the entities in the EDM!  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, are you making a generic EntityFramework management studio or something?

Answer (score 0):

The EDM Model that derives from the ObjectContext has the ConnectionString name which it passes to the base constructor from it's own default constructor. Like below.

```
    public const string ConnectionString = "name=My_Entities";
    public const string ContainerName = "My_Entities";

    #region Constructors

    public My_Entities()
        : base(ConnectionString, ContainerName)
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    #endregion
```

You can always change the Connection details via the ObjectContext.Connection.

Comment: This is a parameterless constructor, but it requires a config file entry with that name containing the connection string.  I need to be able to pass in a string or a ready-to-go EntityConnection, which I can't do use CreateInstance.